# Swift addGestureRecognizer: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

Can't figure this one out... I'm adding a gestureRecognizer for a view inside a ContainerView, but it's returning Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. What am I doing wrong?:

This is inside the VC that has the container view:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EmbedMenu" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? MenuViewController {
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #seclector(tapHamburger)
            vc.hamburgerBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tap) // Optional unwrapping error happens here
        }
    }
}

/* --------- GESTURE METHODS ---------- */
/* ----------------------------------- */
func tapHamburger() {
    if hamburgerOpen {
        hamburgerOpen = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.masterContainer.frame.origin.x = self.masterContainerX
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        hamburgerOpen = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.masterContainer.frame.origin.x += 220
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And this is the container view's embedded VC:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var hamburgerBtn: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't include code as a screenshot, use proper code formatting. Moreover, your selector syntax is wrong, no need for the `(_:)` part.

Comment: @DávidPásztor - I wouldn't say his selector syntax is wrong. Sure, the `(_:)` isn't technically required in this case, but it's what autocomplete suggests and it's certainly not wrong. (Personally, I think it's good practice to include it.)

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor I was really just playing around with that actually, I wasn't sure if it was now required because of Swift 4 or something, or if that might of been giving me an error for some reason. I've removed it now since it's not necessary in this case. I used screenshots because I wanted to show exactly where the error is without typing it out to explain.

Comment: Removed the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hamburgerBtn` is optional. It will be implicitly unwrapped but it's still an optional. Since you have it marked with `@IBOutlet` I'd assume that the button is defined in a storyboard. What that means is the variable will be nil until the view loads. So you can use it in or after MenuViewController's `viewDidLoad` is called.

The problem is `viewDidLoad` will be called after `prepare(for:sender:)` is called.

You could add a variable to MenuViewController to hold the gesture recognizer. Set the variable in `prepare` method and add it to the view in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize prepareForSegue fires before viewDidLoad. This makes more sense. The other responder's suggestion of using a delegate-protocol pattern instead seems like the best solution in my case, but I found your answer the most helpful to explain the reason why I was getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

Outlets to destination's view controller have not been hooked up by the time `prepare(for:sender:)` is called. That outlet is `nil`. You should not reference outlets in the destination controller's view hierarchy from `prepare(for:sender:)`.

Besides, one view controller has no business hooking up gesture recognizes to another view controller's views. The destination should set up its own gesture recognizers and if you want it to inform the parent/presenting view controller of the tap, implement a delegate-protocol pattern.

Comment: Thank you, I will set up a delegate-protocol pattern